# File not found at path - From Remote server

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to read files sent from my users using the filepath. When the file is sent to the api, my callback is invoked with the details as below

**CallBack**

```
array (
      'caption' => 'domainsheet.xlsx',
      'url' => 'https://document.domain.io/media/folder/4b030572-5043-4c33-a394-22c908256f3d',
      'contentType' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    ),
```

**Controller**

In my controller, i specify the file path but it throws the error

> File not found at path: https://document.domain.io/media/folder/4b030572-5043-4c33-a394-22c908256f3d

```
$file_path = 'https://document.domain.io/media/folder/4b030572-5043-4c33-a394-22c908256f3d';
$theArray = Excel::toArray([], $file_path);
Log::info('Content excel');
Log::info($theArray);
```

I also tried to include the content type like (xlsm)
**https://document.domain.io/media/folder/4b030572-5043-4c33-a394-22c908256f3d.xlsm** but the file is still not found.

Could it be i am missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a filesystem in `config/filesystems.php` for domain.io and create a import class [as shown here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html#importing-basics)
You can then use the import as

```php
Excel::import(new YourImportClass, '4b030572-5043-4c33-a394-22c908256f3d.xlsx', 'domainFilesystem')
```

You might need to set the **root** of your filesystem to `https://documents.domain.io/media/folder` or to the appropriate directory for domain.io

check out [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#configuration) for more info on how to configure filesystems